# In regards to the Beal's conjecture

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conjectures, fermat-numbers

Studying the Beal's conjecture, it states: $A^x + B^y = C^z$, where $A, B, C, x, y$ and $z$ are positive integers and $x, y$ and $z$ are all greater than $2$, then $A, B$ and $C$ must have a common prime factor.

It made me think of why the rule doesn't apply if $x$ or $y$ or $z$ equal $2$, and so I collected some data to try and find any difference.

The only thing that seems different is that:

$\textrm{For } A^3\!: \ (A^3 - A) \bmod 3 = 0$

For $A^4$: $(A^4 - A^2) modulo 3 = 0$

For $A^5$: $(A^5 - A) modulo 3 = 0$  |  $(A^5 - A^3) modulo 3 = 0$ *

So when it comes to $A^x$ where $x$ is bigger than 2, the rule is always $(A^x - A^{x-2}) modulo 3 = 0$

And the same doesn't exist for $A^2$ where it is *always ($modulo 3 = 0$)

- I mention *always as visualized in the image below

My question is if there might be a connection to Beal's Conjecture (or at least partially, while considering that $(A^x - A^{x-2}) + (B^y - B^{y-2}) = (C^z - C^{z-2})$ where $x,y,z$ are bigger than 2

(Please see the image as a reference)

I am well aware that this doesn't solve the Beal's conjecture, and my intent is solely to seek any references, opinions or an answer for whether there might be a connection.

[image]

Comment: One can prove that it is false that if $A^x - A^{x-2} +B^y - B^{y-2} = C^z - C^{z-2}$ where $A, B, C, x, y$ and $z$ are positive integers and $x, y$ and $z$ are all bigger than $2$, then $A, B$ and $C$ must have a common prime factor. A counterexample is $4^3-4^1+2^4-2^2=3^4-3^2$.

Comment: @mathlove You are correct, but then again $4^3$ can be written an $8^2$ and $2^4$ can be written an $4^2$

Comment: Then, how about $2^3-2^1+6^3-6^1=3^5-3^3$ ?

Comment: @mathlove Once again you are correct, I guess I have an angle to continue my study. Just out of curiosity, do you know of any examples that don't include $2$ as a base?

Comment: Yes, I do : $3^5-3^3+5^3-5^1=7^3-7^1$